# Resuming stopped process doesn't resume its children

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, operating-system

I wrote a mock mini-shell program which could accept user commands just as a shell would. I am trying to replicate the functionality of stopping/resuming a process launched from within my mini-shell.

I was able to intercept and handle the SIGTSTP signal to stop a long-running process (w/o stopping my mini-shell) which simply echoes "Hi" every X seconds.

[image]

I was also able to resume the long-running process using `kill(pid, SIGCONT);` (in this case `kill(2903651, SIGCONT)` will be executed). Problem is, the `sleep` child process still remains in a stopped state and the "Hi" messages doesn't resume printing. Other processes which doesn't have a child process works just fine.

[image]

My question is, are there any ways to make the process of the given pid resume entirely, including its children?

Comment: The parent needs to handle SIGCONT and then explicitly send a SIGCONT to each of the children in order to resume them.

Comment: The caveat here is that we have no control over the parent process (`repeatHi`) that was launched from the mini-shell (otherwise it defeats the purpose). I can get the PID of repeatHi easily since that was `fork-exec`-ed from the mini-shell, but I also need to recursively get the PIDs of the children (and grandchildren) spawned from the repeatHi process in the mini-shell somehow?

Comment: Instead of sending SIGCONT to the parent, send it to the process group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the parent didn't change the process group of the children (and grandchildren), you should be able to use `killpg()` to signal the entire process group. By default, the process group will have the same value as the parent PID and will include all of PID's children.

In your example above, that would be:

```
killpg(2903651, SIGCONT);
```

For testing purposes, inside a shell, you can accomplish the same thing by specifying the parent PID as the process group, as a negative, e.g.

```
kill -CONT -2903651
```